# Please Help Me, How to Fix PHP Error Undefined Array Key "srcset"

Tags: errors, warnings, wp-error

please help me, my website notice error Message.

On error.log notice Undefined Array Key "srcset"

This is my code on WordPress, and i'am use PHP Version 8.0.

```
function my_plugin_filter_attachment_webp( $attr ) {
global $webp;
if ( ! is_singular( array( 'post', 'page' ) ) && ! ( is_home() || is_tag() || is_category() || is_tax() ) || ( true !== $webp ) || ( is_admin() ) ) {return $attr; } else {
$attr['src'] = str_replace( array( '.jpeg' ), '.jpeg.webp', $attr['src'] );
$attr['src'] = str_replace( array( '.jpg' ), '.jpg.webp', $attr['src'] );
$attr['src'] = str_replace( array( '.png' ), '.png.webp', $attr['src'] );
$attr['srcset'] = str_replace( array( '.jpeg' ), '.jpeg.webp', $attr['srcset'] );
$attr['srcset'] = str_replace( array( '.jpg' ), '.jpg.webp', $attr['srcset'] );
$attr['srcset'] = str_replace( array( '.png' ), '.png.webp', $attr['srcset'] );
return $attr;
}
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'my_plugin_filter_attachment_webp', 10, 1 );
```

How to fix, my dear friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest versions of PHP get mad if you try to reference array parameters that don't exist. It's  a 'warning' type error, so the page will still load.

You need to test for existence of an array parameter before you reference it. So instead of

```
$attr['srcset'] = str_replace( array( '.jpeg' ), '.jpeg.webp', $attr['srcset'] );
```

Put those array references in an IF statement

```
if (isset($attr['srcset']) {
   $attr['srcset'] = str_replace( array( '.jpeg' ), '.jpeg.webp', $attr['srcset'] );
}
```

That will eliminate that warning message. You will have to do similar to all array elements that may not exist.

You also do something like this:

```
$attr['srcset'] = ($attr['srcset']) ? str_replace( array( '.jpeg' ), '.jpeg.webp', $attr['srcset'] ) : "";
```

Which will set that array element to blank if it doesn't exist, so you won't have to test for it the next time you use it.